Serialize a UrlTree in Angular to a parent route in Angular 16
I have a situation where I need to pass a URL to routerLink via <a [routerLink]="targetUrl"></a>. The targetUrl is received as an @Input from a parent component.
There are a number of cases I want to support:

/
../
/some/path/with?query=params

Because I want to support query parameters while not adding an extra input to the component, I decided to parse the query parameters from the targetUrl using a pipe to get here:
<a
  [routerLink]="targetUrl | urlPathParser"
  [queryParams]="queryParams"
></a>

where queryParams looks like:
public get queryParams(): Params {
  return this.router.parseUrl(this.targetUrl).queryParams;
}

and the urlPathParser pipe looks like follows:
@Pipe({
  name: 'urlPathParser',
  standalone: true,
})
export class UrlPathParserPipe implements PipeTransform {
  private router = inject(Router);

  public transform(value: string): string {
    const parsedUrl = this.router.parseUrl(value);
    parsedUrl.queryParams = {};
    return this.router.serializeUrl(parsedUrl);
  }
}

The problem with this approach is that ../ gets serialised to /../ which is wrong. I have read that this is just the behaviour of the default serializer.
Is there some other way that I would be able to support parent navigation while keeping things relatively simple as they are now and without really adding an extra input binding (the chain to get to this component is quite long by now)?

This seems like a simple edge case, where the parser always adds a / to the beginning, this problem is for only relative routes, a simple if condition can remedy this.
@Pipe({
  name: 'urlPathParser',
  standalone: true,
})
export class UrlPathParserPipe implements PipeTransform {
  private router = inject(Router);

  public transform(value: string): string {
    const parsedUrl = this.router.parseUrl(value);
    parsedUrl.queryParams = {};
    let parsed = this.router.serializeUrl(parsedUrl);
    if (value.startsWith('../') || value.startsWith('./')) {
      parsed = parsed.slice(1);
    }
    return parsed;
  }
}

Working Example:
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, UrlSegmentGroup } from '@angular/router';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  router = inject(Router);
  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    ['/', '../', '/../', './../', '/some/path/with?query=params'].forEach(
      (value: string) => {
        const parsedUrl = this.router.parseUrl(value);
        console.log(parsedUrl);
        parsedUrl.queryParams = {};
        let parsed = this.router.serializeUrl(parsedUrl);
        if (value.startsWith('../') || value.startsWith('./')) {
          parsed = parsed.slice(1);
        }
        console.log(parsed);
      }
    );
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. A url such as /some/path/with?query=params gets encoded to /some/path/with%3Fquery%3Dparams

@StanleyClark updated my answer!

You could just remove the query string from the URL instead of parsing it using the angular router.
@Pipe({
  name: 'urlPathParser',
  standalone: true,
})
export class UrlPathParserPipe implements PipeTransform {
  private router = inject(Router);

  public transform(value: string): string {
    const [path] = value.split('?');
    return path;
  }
}


That's a nice idea. I was looking for a solution that wouldn't rely so much on string 'magic' though. Surely something like that exists in the angular universe? This is my fallback option though.

as you can see, the DefaultUrlSerializer always appends a leading slash to the path: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/router/src/url_tree.ts#L403C1-L411C4     I guess you could provide your own UrlSerializer that maintains a relative path but I think that would be more magical than relying on the actual standardized format of an URL.
